# Cassandra downgrade 3.0.3 to 2.1.12

Tags: cassandra

I had recently downgraded after taking all the keyspaces backup from 3.0.3 to 2.1.12.

After that, I am not able to see the user keyspaces.

Steps did that.

1. Drained the node.
2. Stop the cassandra and removed the 3.x version and installed 2.x version
3. Removed the commit log 6.x version, Started the cassandra.
4. Ran the nodetool upgradesstables.

After that,

cqlsh> describe keyspaces;

system_traces  system

cqlsh>

I don't see any user keyspaces. I do have complete backup of data directory.

How to restore the same ?

Let me know.

Comment: You could try this to see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579495/unable-to-see-all-keyspaces-in-c-2-1-7-after-i-downgraded-from-3-0-to-2-1-7/46605809#46605809

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to see all keyspaces in C\* 2.1.7 after I downgraded from 3.0 to 2.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579495/unable-to-see-all-keyspaces-in-c-2-1-7-after-i-downgraded-from-3-0-to-2-1-7)